How do I arrange windows at the top and bottom with the square in Windows 11?
I use Windows 11/64. The small square at the top left of a window allows you to arrange the window on the desktop: e.g. left, right, top right, bottom left, etc.

I'm missing the top and bottom setting. I can arrange it manually of course, but I want the square to offer the top/bottom option. How can I configure it?
++++++++++++++++++++++++ Workaround +++++++++++++
I couldn't extend the hover square for bottom(top). However, you can use the following keyboard shortcuts:
Windows + Alt + Up or Down Arrow


Would additional software be ok? the current windows powertoys has a really nice tool called fancyzones that'd let you this and more.
